# How to get last letters from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
str = '"Apples" AND "Bananas" OR Gala Me'
```

I want to get the 'Gala Me' bit at the end. The words 'AND', 'OR', or anything between quotes can be considered a token. I have this regular expression.

```
regex = /AND|OR|"[^"]+"/g
```

It matches all my tokens but how could I get the opposite of this regex to get the unmatched substring?

Comment: what about using ^ (not)

Comment: wat? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: a regular expression that matches anything after the last 'AND' or 'OR'

Comment: @JanDvorak The goal is clearly stated above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `split()` the string using the tokens:

```
var parts = str.split(/\s*(?:AND|OR|"[^"]+")\s*/)

// ["", "", "", "", "Gala Me"]
```

Optionally, you can filter them by length:

```
var parts = str.split(/\s*(?:AND|OR|"[^"]+")\s*/).filter(function(s) {
    return s.length > 0;
});

// ["Gala Me"]
```

Afterwards, you select the last element (if applicable):

```
if (parts.length) {
  console.log(parts.pop());
}

// "Gala Me"
```

Comment: a most pleasing solution, kudos

Comment: And a one liner: `var last = str.split(/\s*(?:AND|OR|"[^"]+")\s*/).pop();`

Answer (score 0):

> regular expression that matches anything after the last 'AND' or 'OR'

```
.*(?:AND|OR)(.*)$
------------
 |
 |->matches greedily until the last AND or OR
```

Group 1 captures your required string..

Comment: Should this be `.*AND|OR(.*)$` ?

Comment: @iambriansreed that would match anything **upto** AND or that **starts** with OR

Comment: @spinners well..i ans your comment above..you should be clear about what you want

Comment: @spinners: It is to be used with `match`, not `split`